# Can a user be revoked from Keybase?

Tags: keybase

We're considering using Keybase for sharing sensitive information across a distributed team.

However, one thing is not clear for me: what if someone leaves the company and his access to a directory needs to be revoked for all devices he has? Given the distributed nature of the tool, is it possible?

I don't know too much about keychains and don't understand the algorithmic side of Keybase, so I hope I at least put the question correctly.